# Is it possible for a database connection made from the application to the SQL Server to be lost, but the query continues to run?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database-connection

Sorry, if this is a silly question, but I am not an application developer, so I am not sure about all the ins and outs of SQL Server connection management.  My question is pretty much contained in the Title: Is it possible for a database connection made from say a .NET application to be lost, but the query continues to run? Maybe an application server crashed, or some other unexpected event happened to the application.

I understand that if it's a transaction it will either complete in its entirety or fail, but what if it's a multi-statement non-transactional script?

P.S. If this is not possible, they you can just say so, but if it's possible, I would appreciate some link(s) describing when this can happen.

Comment: You need to provide more context, are you trying to explain some behaviour you are observing? Or trying to predict possible error conditions? As written the answer is no.

Comment: Theoretically the server may not realize the connection is lost if there was no TCP RST packet received (eg a broken cable) but some DML query continues until commit. Usually at some point the server notices (usually when it tries to send a DONE or DONE_IN_PROC packet) and then aborts the rest of the batch/procedure (causing a rollback).

Comment: @DaleK, to answer your question, I am thinking, for example, of an application timeout. Let's say application has a timeout of 30 seconds, but the query takes several minutes to run. In this case, the application will timeout, but I am thinking the query may continue to run until completion, however I am not sure, hence my question

Comment: No it won't....

Comment: If there is a timout while still connected then the client sends an ATTENTION packet which usually aborts the query within a reasonable amount of time.